# How to Upload and Run NextJs App Router v14 build to AWS S3 ? If possible then how?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, build, next.js13

Almost possible in NextJS App Router v13,
But how to upload Next JS App Router v14 Build on AWS S3 Bucket ?

I built the build with the **npm run build** command, But how to upload Build in the AWS S3 Bucket,
How its Work in Bucket ?

I haven't done the try but how to do it ?